# Gmail can't be use in third-party component without using Ouath 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, gmail-imap

I read [this article](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2020/03/less-secure-app-turn-off-suspended.html).

1. Gmail can't be use in third-party component without using OAuth 2.0?
2. Should a personal account also use the OAuth 2.0 when using a third-party library?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gmail or any other Google API you should be using OAuth 2 flow to ensure a more security scenario.

For your actual questions, yes you need to use OAuth flow to authenticate to any Google API as required, the link you posted about [Less Secure Apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) already says that they will be deprecated anytime soon and are pretty much discouraged.